# which cell the user push

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm using CEWendel/SWTableViewCell (link here: https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell). Someone knows who i can know which cell swype in tableView.

My code runs averithing ok but i can'n know if the cell is 1, 2, 3... Because i need a particular transition for each one.

The delegate of the librery has a lot of methods but no one says me the number of the cell and if the user don't push in the cell, i don't knows how i can do.

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state;
- (BOOL)swipeableTableViewCellShouldHideUtilityButtonsOnSwipe:(SWTableViewCell *)cell;
- (BOOL)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell canSwipeToState:(SWCellState)state;
- (void)swipeableTableViewCellDidEndScrolling:(SWTableViewCell *)cell;
```

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerome Diaz and Matthias Bauch for you help!!!

Comment: You should accept one of these answers. Maybe you should [take the Stackoverflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how things work around here.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Answer (score 0):

A SWTableViewCell is a UITableViewCell, so

UITableView 
    - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell

method should work

Answer (score 0):

Exemple:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerLeftUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
   // get swiped cell indexPath like this
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

}
```